# Data Annotation MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to use DataAnnotations to restrict user from enter special character?

I want the user to enter only A-Z, a-z and 0-9 into a textbox.

I need to do this on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use Regular Expression for that...

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Foo !")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Entry dude !")]
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try using the [`[RegularExpression]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")]
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

It supports unobtrusive client side validation as well, so this regex will be transposed on the client.

Comment: @123456789, if this answer helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a RegularExpression attribute for that, not sure how well it works with client-side tho.

```
[RegularExpression(@"your-reg-exp", ErrorMessage = "Your error message")]
```