# Special Characters with Data Annotation MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I have done a validations using MVC4 Data Annotations.

And i restricted the Special characters too.

**But i want to allow Spaces between each words**.

I tried this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Name should not be empty")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Special character should not be entered")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

Right now system is not allowing me to Insert. Because i have entered a space. Its considering the space as special char.

How do i allow space? the same time the above validation should work.

Comment: I refered this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554893/data-annotation-mvc3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myself found the answer.

Instead of `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` we need to add like this `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9'' ']+$"`.

`''Single Space'` in the Expression

```
'' '
```

For more information I'd suggesting reading - [Using Data Annotations to Customize Data Classes (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I just came across your answer and just wanted to mention that the single quotes are not needed. You just need the space inside the brackets.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to add like this

Change symbol "+" to "*" (after close square brackets)

#### Correct answer is :

###### @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).